# Mongoose get all value where balance is negative

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to get all data from a collection where balance is negative.

```
let data = await Model.find({ subStaffType: 3, balance < 0  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the MongoDB [less than](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/#mongodb-query-op.-lt) query operator.

```js
let data = await Model.find({ subStaffType: 3, balance: { $lt: 0 })
```

I advice you to read the MongoDB documentation first and get acquainted with the various query operators. Mongoose is a wrapper for the native MongoDB driver, so the query syntax and the supported operators are the same.